# PHP ZIP generating Same File Size

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to generate and force download a ZIP file that contains a sequence of photos listed from a database table.

Everything seems to be working great, but I can't seem to figure out why the photos keep downloading at the same file size.

I'm assuming the files arn't being compressed correctly, I thought it might be the headers but I'm just not sure.

Could anybody shed some light on my problem?

**CODE:**

```
require ("zipfile.inc.php");
$zipfile = new zipfile();
$filedata = implode("", file("zipfile.inc.php"));

$getspdi = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wedding_photos` WHERE `user_hash` = '$logged[ip]' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 1000") or die(mysql_error());
$getspd = mysql_fetch_array($getspdi);

while ($photos = mysql_fetch_array($getspdi)) {
     $zipfile->add_file($filedata, "$photos[img]");
}

header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=szipfile.zip");
echo $zipfile->file();
```

I'm using an exsisting class called "zipfile.inc.php" (http://www.devco.net/code/zipfile.inc.txt).

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: JPG Pictures are already compressed internally try to zip them on your computer and see the resulting size. Most of them can only be compressed by 1% or less. Try a BMP that is uncompressed.

Comment: For example, if there 10 photos in the ZIP (.jpg, .png etc) they all seem to be exactly 7,136 bytes :/ and do not render when trying to preview.

Comment: @Nobody, suggesting he use a BMP slightly defeats the purpose of zipping in the first place.  A Jpg is probably better compressed already than a bmp that is put in a zip file!

Comment: This is all true, but not his issue. The compressed file size will always differ from the original size *somewhat.*

Comment: @Toby Allen: He should use the BMP to test if the zipping works correct and not in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line makes no sense:

```
 $zipfile->add_file($filedata, "$photos[img]");
```

With that, you are adding the contents of `zipfile.inc.php` and giving it the image's name.

You need to fetch the actual image data from somewhere.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Alex where is your actual image data located? The image file itself?

Comment: In a sub directory, the $photos[img] will display "/weddinguploads/name-of-image.jpg"

Comment: @Alex then use e.g. `file_get_contents($photos["img"]);` instead of `$filedata` to provide the actual file data. However, you will need to prefix the correct full path for it to work (`/weddinguploads....` is not a full path in itself)

Comment: How would I run file_get_contents within $zipfile->add_file($filedata, "$photos[img]"); ?

Comment: @Alexwhin just put it instead of `$filedata`

Comment: It turned the filesize into just 7 bytes. Same result through. I placed the full file path.

Comment: @Pekka let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2459/discussion-between-alexwhin-and-pekka)

Comment: @Alex look into the 7 bytes. What do they contain?

Comment: Th file actually contains the words "get_file_contents"

Comment: @Alex do not use quotes. Use `$zipfile->add_file(file_get_contents($photos[img]), "$photos[img]");`, plus the prefix for the full path (that one with quotes)

Comment: The files have no file size now.

Comment: @Alex then you'll need to start debugging to see where the problem is exactly. Is the file path correct, does `file_get_contents()` return the correct file data, etc. etc.

Comment: I'm assuming I'm doing this wrong then, but I'm using the http path.

Comment: @Alex that's probably it - you need to use the filesystem path here.

Comment: I tried using "/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/httpdocs-entertainment" but still 0 bytes. (With photo attached on the end)

Comment: @Alex use `file_exists()` to find out whether the file path actually exists.

Comment: $zipfile->add_file(file_get_contents($photos[img]), "/var/www/vhosts/soundboxaudio.com/httpdocs-entertainment$photos[img]");

Comment: @Alex you need to add the file path to the first occurrence of `$photos["img"]`, not the second. `file_get_contents()` needs the full path to actually open the file.

Answer (score 2):

Most image formats are already compressed. That includes JPEG, PNG and GIF. You cannot compress files in such formats much further using ZIP compression. Indeed, some of the formats are already using the same compression algorithm, which makes it virtually impossible to decrease the size anything at all.

Comment: It's not for compression really, more for transport. The Zip will contain hundreds of photos that need to be downloaded regularly, for a photo display.